# Schedule Windows Service with Quartz.NET

Tags: c#, windows-services, quartz.net

I want to schedule my windows service with Quartz.NET.I tried some examples but,i can't schedule my windows service.How can i do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Well, you're not actually "scheduling" your windows service. The Quartz.Net *server* can run as a windows service and then look at your quartz_jobs.xml to determine the time/frequency (or whatever you have setup as a trigger) to fire your jobs you have defined.

Check out this blog post series for more info - http://jvilalta.blogspot.com/2009/03/getting-started-with-quartznet-part-1.html

It was helpful for me to get started versus the tutorials on the Quartz.Net site.

Answer (score 1):

It's work for me :

"A quick way to create a windows service using Autofac, Quartz and Atlas"

http://www.markjourdan.name/a-quick-way-to-create-a-windows-service-using-autofac-quartz-and-atlas

Comment: Can you add some context to the link?

Comment: I had the same problem to run Quartz.Net as windows service, this site shows with use Autofac, Quartz and Atlas to run as a windows service.

What's your question ?